# mod_rewrite match from start of URI

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Good afternoon,
I am having considerable difficulty getting my mod_rewrite rules to match from the start of the URI. I've looked through the manual but I must be missing some (probably obvious) syntax voodoo. Please consider the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}              ^/(.*)/(foo|bar)/(.*) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/            destination.php?first=$1&second=$2&third=$3              [QSA,L]
```

If the 2nd URI parameter is foo or bar, (e.g. url.com/first/foo/third) this successfully redirects to destination, with the relevant parameters.

If foo or bar are present in the 3rd parameter (e.g. url.com/first/second/foo), I want a different redirect to occur. However, the following rule is ignored, with the above rule still taking priority

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}              ^/(.*)/(something-else)/(.*) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/            destination.php?first=$1&second=$2&third=$3              [QSA,L]
```

I think I must be missing an obvious way of forcing the rewrite to only match from the beginning of the URI- I've tried prepending slashes to try to force it to the root level, but without any joy so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

**Edit**
As it turns out, this was due to a basic RegEx mistake, rather than my mistakenly assuming the match needed to begin from the start of the URI. I won't edit the title as others may make a similar mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.*` is too greedy. Try these 2 rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(foo|bar)/([^/]+)/?$ destination.php?first=$1&second=$2&third=$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(foo|bar)/?$ destination2.php?first=$1&second=$2&third=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Ahh, I see! It didn't occur to me that the RegEx would rollover and eat the / as well. Wonderful, this worked like a charm. Many thanks.